# QuickBooks Online Edition - Integration with ASP.NET using client certificate

Tags: certificate, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I want to integrate QuickBooks Online Edition (QBOE) with my web application. I have been able to subscribe, get connection/temp session ticket etc but the only problem is that I am unable to setup the server to use the certificate required by Intuit. It has been almost 3 weeks but I could not find the exact steps to install and POST a QBXML request to the Intuit's gateway without sacrificing on the server security.

I have the TWO cerificates generated by Intuit when the application is registered. I would appreciate if someone who has integrated QBOE could help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the problem was resolved by one of my colleague who is not available for comments. He used the WinHttpCertCfg tool to change some permissions on the server.
Also, the following link might help:

https://idnforums.intuit.com/messageview.aspx?catid=50&threadid=6192